# Update controller variable from visualforce button/div onclick

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, onclick

I am having issues with my visualforce page refreshing everytime I perform an onclick action? Any ideas

```
public without sharing class LMS_CaseNewEditController {

    public Boolean recordClicked        {get;set;}

    public void recordClicked() {
        recordClicked = true;
    }
}
```

On my visualforce page I have a apex:function, div class over an iframe and javascript function as below.

**Javascript Function**

```
function remove(){
    console.log('click');
    var x = document.getElementById("bar1");
    recordClicked();
    return x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
    }
```

**Apex & div**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="recordClicked" action="{!recordClicked}"></apex:actionFunction>
<div id="box" draggable="true" align="right" style="padding-right: 10px">
    <apex:outputPanel id="ILOSbutton" rendered="{!isDisplayRecorder}" >
        <div id="iFrameWrapper" class="holder">
             <div id="bar1" class="bar" onmousedown="remove()"></div>
                  <apex:iframe id="myFrame" src="{!iframeString}" height="40px" width="140px"></apex:iframe>
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-6" style="width: 300px;text-align: right" >{!$Label.ILOS_Help_Text}</label>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
     </div>
```

Essentially what should happen is the value should update on the controller side without refreshing the page. Any ideas?

Comment: `apex:actionFunction` misses rerender tag

Comment: Would i set it to false or?

Comment: Ok ive set it to false and the page no longer refreshes but the alert on the javascript function isn't working?

Comment: Your VF page uses `isDisplayRecorder` which is nowhere in the class. Do check the code once. Also  as @RahulSharma pointed, the rerender is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `rerender` property to the `apex:actionFunction` tag. in the `rerender` property you want to add the ID of the tag you want to rerender. That way the page won't refresh it will just rerender the specific tag. So your `apex:actionFunction` should look like this:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="recordClicked" action="{!recordClicked}" rerender="tagID"></apex:actionFunction>
```